# Is there a comprehensive list of Device information available through WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

There are things I want to know about the device. Is it ARM or Intel? Does it support Bluetooth? What version of Windows is the user running? What is the resolution of the device? What is the IP of the device. Things like that. And, I know not everything is available. Instead of a question for every single information datum, is there a comprehensive list (or even a demo) that shows what is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync() to list cameras, mics, audio output devices and external storage. For Accelerometer I think you need to catch exceptions when you try to use one. I doubt there is something to check for ARM/Intel or Windows version, although you can compile separate builds for ARM/Intel and use #defines to check the difference. For screen resolution I would use something like Window.Current.Bounds (assuming you are in full mode). IP, Bluetooth are probably things you might check in their own stacks (never needed those, so not really sure where). I haven't seen a demo that would show all these, but it sounds like something that might be worth adding to the toolkit...

Comment: You can never rule out the existence of something. It's like testing at this level - you can prove something exists, but not that it doesn't. I am pretty sure the list you asked about will pop up somewhere pretty soon.